# How do I subtract the last figure added to a total in VB

Tags: vb.net, math, undo

I want to create a button that will undo a mathematical procedure in VB.NET.

The program consists of a list. The user adds items to this list. These items also have values(prices) attached them. These items are represented by buttons. So when the user clicks on a button, the specific item and its price are placed in the list box.

Below the list box, there is a Total Due textbox. This consists of the total amount that needs to be paid in order to purchase the selected items in the list.

I can easily delete entries in the list by selecting the 'Clear Last Item' button. however the 'Total Due' does not change.

The code i have so far for this is the following:

```
 Private Sub btnClearLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearLast.Click
    'clear the last item to appear in the list box
    If lstOrder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Orders to Clear", "Error")

    ElseIf lstOrder.Items.Count > 0 Then
        lstOrder.Items.RemoveAt(lstOrder.Items.Count - 1)
    End If
 End Sub
```

An image would be ideal but have not got enough reputation to add an image to the question. Hope this helps a little more

Comment: Can we see the code where you add the number to the total?  We need more context.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Is your main concern about how to set up the button, or how to change the app so that operations can be undone?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a stupid but an unclear question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Every time you change the total, save the old value of the total. When the user clicks the "Undo" button, replace the current total with the saved value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have a TextBox (NumberBox) for the user to enter a number, a Label (TotalLabel) where you display the total, a Button (AddButton) to add the number in Numberbox to the total and another button (UndoButton) to undo the last add.

```
Private total, savedTotal As Double, canUndo As Boolean

Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
    Dim number As Double
    If Not Double.TryParse(NumberBox.Text, number) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number")
        Exit Sub 
    End If

    savedTotal = total 
    canUndo = True 
    total += number 
    TotalLabel.Text = total.ToString 
End Sub

Sub UndoButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UndoButton.Click
    If canUndo Then
        total = savedTotal 
        canUndo = False 
        TotalLabel.Text = total.ToString 
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Can't undo")
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this code only supports a single undo operation. If you want multiple undo operations, you will need to store all the previous values in a collection such as a Stack.

Comment: Thank you Blackwood and apologies to everyone else for the initial lack of detail to the question.